# Firefox does not start further downloads after certain number of downloads is active

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-extensions

I i start several file downloads of a given site firefox won't start further downloads - the where to save dialog does not appear until a download is finished.

I guess this is not a problem in Firefox, but is there a way to store the download links and start all downloads later?

years ago i used downthemall but this not working anymore. is there an alternative at least with a feature for delayed downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `about:config` in the address line:
[image]

In the search line, type `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server`:
[image]

Right click on `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server` and choose `modify` (sorry the menu is blurry in the screenshot):
[image]

Enter a larger value (e.g. 10) and click `OK`:
[image]

Note that some sites indeed themselves limit your total number of download connections, but since you noted the "save" dialog didn't even appear, it seems that it wasn't the case there.

As for you latter request of a Firefox download manager extension, SuperUser is not a software recommendation forum, but luckily the Stack Exchange network has such a dedicated site: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks!, i'll try and will accept (i upvoted already)